# Jmeter Debug Sampler | How to save all variable values to CSV

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am able to extract values for many variables and are showing in Debug Sampler.

**Is there any way to save these all variable values to a CSV file?**

I found a solution (using BeanShell script) to save multiple Jmeter variable to CSV but I want all variables values to a single CSV, so that I can use the CSV file for next thread run.

Here is the snapshot of one of the Debug Sampler:

```
enterCompanyname=APITENANT
CreateTenant_Status=Success
CreateTenant_Status_matchNr=1
Current_UTC_Time=2018-03-07T01:53:18.310Z
DB_DataSource=dev4574857
DB_Password=1234
DB_UserName=web
DeviceCount=19
DevicesPerUser=94
EXCELPATH=X:\QualityAssurance\XLSX_3 columns_1000 rows.xlsx
Email=apitenant@apitenant.com
EndDate=2018-12-31
Exist=false
Exist_matchNr=1
FirstName=API
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@69ab73cf
LastName=TENANT
LicensePlan=Pro
LicenseType=Device
MaxUsers=11
Password=Password
Protocol=http
RandomNumber=10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan (where you want variables to be saved)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def csv = new File('vars.csv')
   vars.entrySet().each {var ->
       csv << var.key + '=' + var.value + System.getProperty('line.separator') 
   }
   ```
3. That's it, you will have `vars.csv` file created in JMeter's "bin" folder having all variables listed. You might also want to replace `=` with `,` for better [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) compatibility.

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables.

Also be aware that starting from JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to switch to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and Groovy language so consider migrating to Groovy as soon as it will be possible. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.